# HTML/CSS (render in PDF) display a second page after the footer of the fisrt page

Tags: html, css

I have a page (htlm that will be used only in pdf) build like that :

```
<div>some info here</div> 
<table>a table that can have more or less lines</table>
<div class="footer" style=" bottom: 0; position:fixed; page-break-after: always;">the footer of the page here</div>
<div class="secondPage">another page, without the footer</div>
```

I want the footer to be fixed on the bottom of the fisrt page only, and the second page display after this footer.

The problem here is that the content of the second page (class="secondPage") is displayed just after the table on the the first page and before the footer, and not on another page.

Is there a way to use the position:fixed; and the page-break-after: always; together ?
How can I get what I want to display ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<footer>` element.

The important thing to remember is that the `<footer>` is related to its parent element. If it inside an  element, then it is the footer of that element. If it is the last element inside the  element, then it is the footer of the page as a whole.

If you want to use the footer for the "first page". You need to create it as a parent first and it should contain whatever you want inside including the footer.

For example,

```
<div class="firstPage">
   <div>some info here</div> 
   <table>a table that can have more or less lines</table>
   <div class="footer" style=" bottom: 0; position:absolute; page-break-after: always;">the footer of the page here</div>
</div>

<div class="secondPage">another page, without the footer</div>
```

Comment: so the "page-break-after: always;" should be used in the <div class="firstPage"> instead ?

Comment: This is what page-break-after does -> https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/page-break-after/ . It depends on what you want to use it for. If you want to separate things into "pages" you need to wrap them with a parent element such as I did. So the <footer> works as expected.

Comment: I try that and the second page is displayed as a second page (ok) but the footer is displayed on the 2 pages, not only the first

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the position: fixed. Try changing that to absolute.

Comment: I replaced the fixed by absolute but now everything is displayed on each other... (the footer is underneath the second page content)